# How to access list of list values in columns in dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

In my DataFrame.I am having a list of list values in a column. For example, I am having columns as A, B, C, and my output column. In column A I'm having a value of 12 and in column B I am having values of 30 and in column C I am having a list of values like [0.01,1.234,2.31].When I try to find mean for all the list of list values.It shows list object as no attribute mean.How to convert all list of list values to mean in the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform the column which contains the lists to another DataFrame and calculate the mean.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = ... # Original df
pd.DataFrame(df['column_with_lists'].values.tolist()).mean(1)
```

This would result in a pandas DataFrame which looks like the following:

```
0   mean_of_list_row_0
1   mean_of_list_row_1
.   .
.   .
.   .
n   mean_of_list_row_n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply(np.mean) on the column with the lists in it to get the mean.  For example:

Build a dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[2,4],[4,6]])
df[3] = [[5,7],[8,9,10]]

print(df)

   0  1           3
0  2  4      [5, 7]
1  4  6  [8, 9, 10]
```

Use apply(np.mean)

```
print(df[3].apply(np.mean))

0    6.0
1    9.0
```

If you want to convert that column into the mean of the lists:

```
df[3] = df[3].apply(np.mean)
print(df)

Name: 3, dtype: float64
   0  1    3
0  2  4  6.0
1  4  6  9.0
```